# What 7-zip lzma/lzma2 command line parameters get the fastest decompression?

Tags: compression, 7-zip

What 7-zip lzma/lzma2 command line parameters get the fastest decompression?

Needs to be compatible with `-sfx`.

Comment: That's impossible to answer, since it depends on how the source data was compressed.

Comment: @DavidPostill So the majority of the source data is text files and images if that helps determine best parameters.